# Executing JavaScript to Render HTML for Server-Side Caching

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, greasemonkey

There are lots of widgets provided by sites that are effectively bits of JavaScript that generate HTML through *DOM* manipulation or `document.write()`. Rather than slow the browser down even more with additional requests and trust yet another provider to be fast, reliable and not change the widget output, I want to execute* the JavaScript to generate the rendered HTML, and then save that HTML source.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Things I've looked into that seem unworkable or way too difficult:

1. The Links Browser (*not lynx!*)
2. Headless use of Xvfb plus Firefox plus Greasemonkey (*yikes*)
3. The all-Java browser toolkit Cobra (*the best bet!*)

Any ideas?

** Obviously you can't really execute the JavaScript completely, as it doesn't necessarily have an exit path, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia's ["Server-side JavaScript"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) article lists numerous implementations, many of which are based on Mozilla's **Rhino** JavaScript-to-Java converter, or its cousin **SpiderMonkey** (the same engine as found in Firefox and other Gecko-based browsers). In particular, something simple like [**mod_js**](http://www.modjs.org/) for Apache may suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just using plain JS, [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) should do the trick.  But if the JS code is actually calling DOM methods and so on, you're going to need a full-blown browser. [Crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar) might help you.

Is this really going to make things faster for users without causing compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2):

There's John Resig's project [Bringing the Browser to the Server](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/): "browser/DOM environment, written in JavaScript, that runs on top of [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/); capable of running jQuery, Prototype, and MochiKit (at the very least)."

Comment: Resig's thing is exactly what I'm looking for.